# python merge returns ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to read in two files, one text and one csv, parse them and write out to an excel file containing two sheets.

My merge of the two files returns a ValueError I don't understand.

This is my code :

```
jobs = pd.read_csv(r'test01.txt', delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=[0, 2])
cmdb = pd.read_csv(r'cmdb.csv', encoding='ansi')

# new data frame with split value columns 
new = jobs["Job_Name"].str.split("_", n = 2, expand = True) 

# making seperate App Code column from new data frame 
jobs["appCode"]= new[1] 

# Get unique app codes and sort them
apps = new[1].unique()
apps.sort()

merged = pd.merge(apps,cmdb, left_on="appCode", right_on="application", how='inner')
```

This is the error I'm receving :

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 538, in __init__
    'type {left}'.format(left=type(left)))

ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I'm not clear on how the left value became a class 'numpy.ndarray', and what I can do to correct this.

Appreciate this is probably pretty basic, but I'm new with python and can't seem to wrap my head around this.

The jobs text file I'm reading looks like this -

```
Job_Name                                                         Last Start           Last End             
________________________________________________________________ ____________________ ____________________ 
PRD_ABC_CAT_QUARTERLYJOBS                                        -----                -----                
PRD_UNC_DOG_QUARTERLYZZZZZZZZZZZREPORT                           -----                -----                
PRD_ZYX_DOG_ABCDEF_WHATEVER_BATCH                               09/15/2016 10:00:00  09/15/2016 10:00:00  
PRD_ZYX_DOG_ABCDEF_WHATEVER_TRANSMIT_TW                         09/13/2016 10:00:11  09/13/2016 10:00:12  
PRD_ZYX_DOG_ABCDEF_WHATEVER_ARCHIVE                             09/13/2016 10:00:13  09/13/2016 10:00:13  
PRD_ZYX_DD_ABCDEF_AFFEE_BATCH                                   12/07/2016 20:00:02  12/07/2016 20:00:02  
PRD_ZYX_DD_ABCDEF_AFFEE_BATCH2                                  -----                12/07/2016 20:06:56
```

The cmdb csv file I'm rading looks like this -

```
application,name,status
ABC,GOOFY,LIVE
DEF,PLUTO,UNKNOWN
RRR,DAISY,HOT
UNC,DONALD,DEAD
ZYX,ALVIN,SLEEPING
```

Comment: Showing us (some of) your data would certainly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apps = new[1].unique()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html

`unique` method of pandas returns

`If the input is an Index, the return is an Index
If the input is a Categorical dtype, the return is a Categorical
If the input is a Series/ndarray, the return will be an ndarray`

So `apps` is not a dataframe.

### Sample usage:

```
jobs = pd.DataFrame(
{ 'Job_Name': [ 'PRD_ZYX_DOG_ABCDEF_WHATEVER_BATCH', 'PRD_ZYX_DOG_ABCDEF_WHATEVER_TRANSMIT_TW',
               'PRD_ZYX_DOG_ABCDEF_WHATEVER_ARCHIVE', 'PRD_ZYX_DD_ABCDEF_AFFEE_BATCH'],
  'Last Start': [ 1,2,3,4], 'Last End': [10,20,30,40]})

cmdb = pd.DataFrame({
        'application': ['ABC','DEF','RRR', 'UNC','ZYX'],
        'name': ['GOOFY','PLUTO','DAISY','DONALD','ALVIN'],
        'status': ['LIVE','UNKNOWN','HOT', 'DEAD', 'SLEEPING']})

# Create appCode
jobs["appCode"] = jobs["Job_Name"].str.split("_",  n = 2, expand=True)[1]

# If you want to merge the jobss and cmdb then you can use
merged = pd.merge(jobs,cmdb, left_on="appCode", right_on="application", how='inner')

# Of if you want to filter the contents of cmdb with only the 
# application values from appCode of jobs you can use
filtered = cmdb[cmdb['application'].isin(jobs['appCode'])]
```

If

[image]

Then

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Really appreciate this.